# Extend interface with additional defined field React Typescript

Tags: typescript, react-typescript

I'm trying extend React-Route V6 RouteObject to include an additional field. In the example below I'd like to include a **name** element. My attempt below doesn't work. Can someone please show me what I'm doing wrong. I'm new to TypeScript.

Path: `React-Router V6 RouteObject interface`

```
export interface RouteObject {
  caseSensitive: boolean;
  children?: RouteObject[];
  element: React.ReactNode;
  path: string;
}
```

Path: `My Component`

```
export interface IRouteObject extends RouteObject {
  name: string;
  children?: IRouteObject[];
}

const routes: IRouteObject = [
  {
    path: '/forms',
    element: <FormPage />,
    caseSensitive: true,
    name: 'forms',
    children: [
      { path: '/', element: <p>Name Form</p>, caseSensitive: true, name: 'Name form' },
    ]
  }
]
```

**UPDATE**

**Error message is.
Property 'name' does not exist on type 'RouteObject[]'.**
The error occurs in the code snippet below when I `console.log(childRoute.name)`.

Path: `Nav`

```
const Nav: React.FC<{}> = () => {
  let location = useLocation();
  let routeMatches = matchRoutes(routes, location);

  if (routeMatches && routeMatches.length > 1) {
    const childRoutes = routeMatches[0].route.children;
    
    childRoutes?.map((childRoute, index) => {
      console.log(childRoute.name);
    }

  )}
}
```

Comment: Please share the error you are getting.

Comment: The only error I see is that you used `const routes: IRouteObject = [` instead of `const routes: IRouteObject[] = [`.

Comment: `routes` should be an array, no ? should be `const routes: IRouteObject[] = ...`

Comment: Please find updated code. I've add additional information and the error message. Property 'name' does not exist on type 'RouteObject[]'.

Answer (score 0):

Add a ts file in to do Type augmentation

Add a file like `route-object-expanded.ts` with this content:

```
import "react-router";

declare module "react-router" {
  interface IndexRouteObject {
    name?: string;
  }
  interface NonIndexRouteObject {
    name?: string;
  }
}
```